# How to do storage replication on Windows Server 2012 R2 in a lab?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, storage, replication

I want to mock up an architecture for a proof-of-concept and need to synchronously replicate a volume from one Windows Server 2012 R2 to another. Can anyone suggest a (ideally free) way to do this in a lab environment?

I just want to mock up some ideas before trying them in a "proper" SAN-equipped environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out SDS solutions from HP http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/data-storage/free-vsa.html and StarWind https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-free. They both have free versions, but, if I'm not mistaken, HP VSA can only give you up to 1TB free while StarWind provides unlimited storage capacity.

Comment: The guy in that Starwind video on that link should stop smoking dope before making videos.

Comment: This video reminds me of a Kurt Cobain's "Something In The Way" :)))